# Rsync on windows: Permission Denied (13)

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, rsync

I have a Windows 7 box and an Ubuntu server that I need to sync files between.  My plan was to use Rsync running in cygwin on the Windows machine with a script like this:

```
cd E:/User/
rsync -avz --delete -e "ssh -p 2221" Pictures/* user@sub.host.com:/Path/to/Files/
rsync -avz --delete -e "ssh -p 2221" user@sub.host.com:/Path/to/Files/* Pictures/
```

However when I attempt this, rsync spits out error's like this for every file or dir

```
rsync: recv_generator: fail to stat "/path/to/file/file.jpg": Permission denied (13)
rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/path/to/file/": Permission denied (13)
```

The user I'm ssh'ing into the server as has `drwxrwxrwx` access to the directory (according to `ls -la`).  Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124169/cwrsync-ignores-nontsec-on-windows-7